# How to have a discord bot correctly load a json and print id's correctly

Tags: python, json, string, discord, bots

```
@client.command(aliases=['Add', 'add'])
async def _add(ctx, name: discord.User):
    with open('TrackerBot/tracker.json', 'r') as file: # Adds to the dictionary, the dictionary at that user increases by one simulating a point increase
        dictionary = json.load(file)
        dictionary[str(name.id)] += 1 

    with open("TrackerBot/tracker.json", 'w') as file: # updates the dictionary by dumping json data
        json.dump(dictionary, file)

    await ctx.send(f'Added a point to {name}') # bot sends a message who the point got added too

# Prints the scoreboard out
@client.command()
async def scoreboard(ctx):
    message = ''
    # Message will be the string in the format: Discord user name, score and a newline for each user
    for key, value in data.items():
        message += str(key) + ": " + str(value) + '\n'

    await ctx.send(message)
```

Hi I am creating a discord bot right now that tracks points on a scoreboard. I have 2 issues 1. My JSON file that contains a dictionary of me and my friends discord IDS does not update the score that uses the add function unless I close out the bot and open it again. 2. I can't figure out how to convert a discord id string (key) to a user so that when I print out the score board it prints the username for each person.

Comment: Two questions: have you checked the content of the json file? (without restart your bot). Second: what is `data` in the scoreboard() method?

Comment: The data in the scoreboard is the json file which is a dictionary. The json file contains id's of me and my friends on discord where the id is the key as a string and the value is the amount of points on the scoreboard. When I run the *add command I see it update in the json but when I run the *scoreboard command it doesn't update. I can post all the code for the bot if needed as well or screenshots on imgur of the commands not working.

Comment: In the code you shared, we do not see that `data`  was read from the json file. Probaly would be better if you share the complete code

Comment: https://github.com/EthanA2025/TrackerBot Here is a link to all the code I currently have

Answer (score 0):

It's important that when you ask a question on SO, add all the relevant code. Looking at the link, I see that `data` is read only when the bot starts, so you should do:

```py
# Prints the scoreboard out
@client.command()
async def scoreboard(ctx):
    with open('tracker.json') as file: # Load dictionary (scoreboard) at the start 
        data = json.load(file)
    message = ''
    # Message will be the string in the format: Discord user name, score and a newline for each user
    for key, value in data.items():
        message += str(key) + ": " + str(value) + '\n'

    await ctx.send(message)
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to the website so thanks for letting me know

Comment: I also tried this but I still have the same issue where it outputs 0's for all values even when updated, do you know any other issues I could have?

Comment: Add print() lines to show everytime the the data you are saving and loading in the json file, that will help you to find the problem. Another question: are you running in your local machine or in some service like Heroku?